# Import and use standard Python module from inside Python C extension

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-extensions

I have Python extension module written in C. I want to use in this C code one of the standard Python modules, for example `os` or `shutil`. How is best to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
PyObject* os = PyImport_ImportModuleNoBlock("os");
if (os == NULL)
  return NULL;
someattr = PyObject_GetAttrString(os, "someattr");
Py_DECREF(os);
```

If you import the module only once e.g., in `init_yourmodule()` function then use `PyImport_ImportModule("os")`.

Comment: The function `PyImport_ImportModuleNoBlock` is now [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html#c.PyImport_ImportModuleNoBlock)

Comment: @user yes. Now both functions are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Don't.

Instead, change your extension module so that it provides a service to Python, and then write Python code which calls `os`, `shutil` and your module.

In fact, for a lot of  the content in the `os` module it is probably better to write native C code rather than call into Python.

Of course, [you can call Python modules from C code](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#calling-python-functions-from-c), it's just that doing that is overkill for low level modules like `os` and `shutil`. When it comes to the file copying methods in `shutil` reimplementing them in your C code is trivial. In fact, on Windows, copying a file is done by a call to the OS so there is not much code to even write in C.

If the Python module is written in C you could even just copy the code for the methods that you need.

Comment: Complex extension modules sometimes need to do stuff that was already implemented in stdlib. It's a shame to reimplement them in C, or to restructure the code